# $X_n \to X$ in $L_2$, show that $\lim_{n \to \infty}E[X_n^2]=E[X^2]$

Tags: probability, probability-theory

$X,X_1,...$ are random variables, $X_n \to X$ in $L_2$. Show that $\lim_{n \to \infty}E[X_n^2]=E[X^2]$.

My attempt:

$X_n \to X$ in $L_2 \implies \lim_{n \to \infty} E[(X_n-X)^2]=0 \implies \lim_{n \to \infty} E[X_n^2]-2\lim_{n \to \infty} E[X_nX]=-E[X^2]$

Intuitively I see that $-2\lim_{n \to \infty}E[X_nX]=-2E[X^2]$ (and then the theorem is proved) but can not prove it.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here is an answer that doesn't (explicitly) use normed vector spaces.

Nevertheless, I'd like to mention that, for a given probability space $(\Omega, \mathcal F, P),$ we have the *Hilbert space* $L^2(\Omega) := \{Y:\Omega\rightarrow\mathbb R\ |\ Y\ \mathcal F$-measurable and $E(Y^2) < \infty \}$ with norm $\|Y\| = \bigl(E(Y^2)\bigr)^\frac12$ and scalar product $\langle Y,Z\rangle = E(YZ).$ Along the way I will make some pedagogical remarks about this object. They are completely irrelevant to the understanding of the answer.

So we are concerned with real-valued random variables on $(\Omega, \mathcal F, P).$ We assume that all random variables are finite almost everywhere, because otherwise arithmetic is complicated. We are given that $\lim_{n\rightarrow\infty}E((X_n - X)^2) = 0$ and want to show that $\lim_{n\rightarrow\infty}E(X_n^2) = E(X^2).$ We require some basic facts.

**Fact 1:** Suppose that $E(Y^2) < \infty$ and $E(Z^2) < \infty$. Then we have that $E(YZ)$ exists and
$$
|E(YZ)| \leq E|YZ| < \infty.
$$
Proof: We have
$$
0 \leq (Y+Z)^2 = Y^2 + 2YZ + Z^2\qquad and\ thus\qquad -2YZ \leq Y^2 + Z^2
$$
and also
$$
0 \leq (Y-Z)^2 = Y^2 - 2YZ + Z^2\qquad and\ thus\qquad 2YZ \leq Y^2 + Z^2.
$$
This together shows that
$$
|YZ| \leq \frac12(Y^2 + Z^2).
$$
Taking expectations, we get
$$
E|YZ| \leq \frac12(E(Y^2) + E(Z^2)) < \infty.
$$
Now existence of $E(YZ)$ and $|E(YZ)| \leq E|YZ|$ are clear from general facts about Lebesgue integration. End of proof.

Fact 1 shows that the inner product on $L^2(\Omega)$ is well-defined.

**Fact 2:** Suppose that $E(Y^2) < \infty$ and $E(Z^2) < \infty$. Then we have
$$
E((Y+Z)^2) < \infty.
$$
Proof: According to fact 1, $E(YZ)$ exists and is finite. So we have
$$
E((Y+Z)^2) = E(Y^2 + 2YZ + Z^2) = E(Y^2) + 2 E(YZ) + E(Z^2) < \infty.
$$
End of proof.

Fact 2 basically shows that $L^2(\Omega)$ is a real vector space.

**Fact 3:** Suppose that $E(Y^2) < \infty$ and $E(Z^2) < \infty$. Then we have
$$
(E(YZ))^2 \leq E(Y^2) E(Z^2).
$$
Proof: According to fact 1, $E(YZ)$ exists and is finite. So we have
$$
\forall\lambda\in\mathbb R: 0 \leq E((Y+\lambda Z)^2) = E(Y^2 + \lambda 2YZ + \lambda^2Z^2) = E(Y^2) + \lambda 2E(YZ) + \lambda^2E(Z^2).
$$
This implies that the quadratic equation
$$
0  = E(Y^2) + \lambda 2E(YZ) + \lambda^2E(Z^2)
$$
in $\lambda$ has no or one real solution, but not two real solutions. Now a glance at the well-known [quadratic formula](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Quadratic_formula) tells us that this in turn implies
$$
0 \geq 4(E(YZ))^2 - 4 E(Y^2)E(Z^2),
$$
i.e. the value under the square root in the quadratic formula must not be positive. But this last inequality is exactly what we want. End of proof.

Fact 3 is tha famous [Cauchy-Schwarz inequality](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cauchy%E2%80%93Schwarz_inequality) in Hilbert spaces.

Now we have all the facts that we need. So let's consider the situation at hand, namely
$$
\lim_{n\rightarrow\infty}E((X_n-X)^2) = 0.
$$
Since we are interested in questions about convergence, we also can assume
$$
\forall n\in\mathbb N:E((X_n-X)^2)<\infty
$$
(discarding finitely many $n$ if necessary).

First we assume
$$
E(X^2) < \infty.
$$
Then we get from fact 2 that
$$
E(X_n^2) = E(((X_n-X)+X)^2) < \infty.
$$
With this, fact 1 shows us that $E(X_nX)$ exists and is finite. Moreover, we get from fact 3 that
$$
0 \leq (E(X_nX) - E(X^2))^2 = (E((X_n-X)X))^2 \leq E((X_n-X)^2)E(X^2).
$$
Here, the r.h.s tends to $0$ as $n$ tends to infinity. Thus, we can conclude
$$
\lim_{n\rightarrow\infty}E(X_nX) = E(X^2).
$$
This together with the fact that
$$
0 = \lim_{n\rightarrow\infty}E((X_n-X)^2) = \lim_{n\rightarrow\infty}E(X_n^2 - 2X_nX+X^2) = \lim_{n\rightarrow\infty}(E(X_n^2) - 2E(X_nX) + E(X^2))
$$
implies
$$
0 = \lim_{n\rightarrow\infty}(E(X_n^2) - E(X^2)),
$$
as desired.

Now let's consider the case that
$$
E(X^2) = \infty.
$$
Then we have to show that $E(X_n^2)$ tends to infinity as $n$ tends to infinity. Assume that's not the case. Then, there are a subsequence $n_k$ and a bound $M < \infty$ such that
$$
\forall k\in\mathbb N: E(X_{n_k}^2) < M.
$$
Since $\lim_{n\rightarrow\infty}E((X_n-X)^2) = 0,$ we can thus find an index $m$ such that
$$
E(X_m^2) < M\qquad and \qquad E((X-X_m)^2) < 1.
$$
Now we conclude from fact 2 that
$$
E(X^2) = E(((X-X_m) + X_m)^2) < \infty,
$$
a contradiction. Thus we really must have
$$
\lim_{n\rightarrow\infty}E(X_n^2) = \infty,
$$
as desired.

Comment: I think you are missing two exponents. Where you conclude that $E[X_n^2] = E[(X_n-X)^2 + X^2]$. It's also possible that I'm misinterpreting

Comment: @jameselmore Thanks for mentioning that. I changed it to $E[X_n^2] = E[((X_n-X)+X)^2].$

Comment: @jflipp May I ask a stupid follow up question? If we assume that fact 3 is proven, do we really need to prove facts 1-2 to answer my question? I mean, if we know (assume) that $\forall n\in\mathbb N:E((X_n-X)^2)<\infty$ does not it automatically mean that $\forall n \in \mathbb N : E[X^2],E[X_n^2], E[X*X_n] <\infty$ i.e exist, and if on top of this you have fact 3, you do not need facts 1-2 to finish the proof, do you?

Comment: You're right. Fact 3 is the central piece. There's a reason why this innocent looking little inequality bears the names of two great mathematicians. :-) Facts 1 and 2 are only needed to ensure that if some of the expectations we're working with exist and are finite, then the others do too. If you know beforehand that all occurring resp. required expectations exist and are finite, you don't need facts 1 and 2.

Answer (score 0):

We can use the fact that, on any normed vector space, the norm is a continuous function with respect to the norm topology. Namely, if $V$ is a normed vector space with norm $\|\cdot\|,$ then we have for any $x,y\in V$ the "inverse" triangle inequalitiy
$$
\bigl| \|x\| - \|y\| \bigr| \leq \|x-y\|.
$$
If you haven't seen this before, it follows "easily" from the ordinary triangle inequality.

Now, if we have $z_n \rightarrow z$ in $V,$ then $\|z_n - z\| \rightarrow 0,$ and thus $\|z_n\| \rightarrow \|z\|$ by the inverse triangle inequality. So, indeed, $\|\cdot\|$ is continuous on $V$ with respect to the norm topology.

Of course, all this applies to your situation. Here, we're considering $L^2$ with norm
$$
\|X\| = \bigl(E(|X|^2)\bigr)^\frac12.
$$
So, if $X_n \rightarrow X$ in $L^2,$ then $\|X_n\| \rightarrow \|X\|$ and thus also
$$
E(|X_n|^2) = \bigl(\|X_n\|\bigr)^2 \rightarrow \bigl(\|X\|\bigr)^2 = E(|X|^2),
$$
as desired.

Comment: thanks for the answer, can you please dumbify it a notch for me? Is it possible to prove the theorem without (directly) using the fact that $\|X\| = \bigl(E(|X|^2)\bigr)^\frac12$ is a norm for the vector space of random variables defined for a probability space $(\Omega,\mathcal F,P)$?